# TableViewController inside TabViewController inside NavigationViewController not showing navigation title and item in runtime, but shows in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar, xcode7-beta5

I have a TableViewController inside a TabViewController inside a NavigationController with navigation title and item, as seen here: 
[image]

On runtime, navigation bar is there, but title and add item are not shown, as seen here: (don't mind the white emptiness, in my device its working, but not in the simulator - I asked about it in stackOverflow, but still no solution)
[image]

The other TabBar item is pointing at a regular UIView, which is also not showing navigation bar title and bar item.

I tried to add another UIView, which will be a mediator between TabBarViewController and TableViewController, and that fixed the problem, but that made me lose the TabBar functionality in my TableViewController.
I tried to point at the navigation bar from my TableViewController, but methods like "viewDidAppear" or navigationBar Class are not accessible from there, as it is acting as a controller for tableView.

**TableViewController Class**

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class MeetsTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

// Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
    //self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // Configure the PFQueryTableView
    self.parseClassName = "Meets";
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true;
    self.textKey="city";
    self.paginationEnabled = false;

}


// Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Meets");
    query.orderByDescending("numberOfComming");
    return query;
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell") as! CarTableViewCell!;

    if cell == nil {
        cell = CarTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "MyCell");
    }
    if let cityName = object?["city"] as? String{
        cell?.meetName?.text = "מפגש ב\(cityName)";
    }
    if let address = object?["address"] as? String{
        cell?.meetAddress?.text = address;
    }
    if let date = object?["date"] as? String{
        cell?.meetDate?.text = date;
    }
    if let time = object?["time"] as? String{
        cell?.meetTime?.text = time;
    }
    if let people = object?["numberOfComming"] as? Int{
        cell?.peopleAttending?.text = "\(people)";
    }

    if let thumbnail = object?["meetImg"] as? PFFile {

        thumbnail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (imageData, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                cell.meetImage.image = image
            }
        }
    }

    return cell;
}

//delegate method
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    moveToDetail();
}

func moveToDetail(){
    let meetDetail=storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("meet") as! MeetDetailViewController;

    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let row = Int(indexPath.row);
        meetDetail.currentObject = (objects?[row] as? PFObject)
    }
    navigationController?.showViewController(meetDetail, sender: self);
}

}
```

**TabViewController Class**

```
import UIKit

class MeetingsTabViewControllerViewController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // set red as selected background color
    let numberOfItems = CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
    let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width / numberOfItems, height: tabBar.frame.height)
    tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(UIColor(hexString: "#8c332b")!, size: tabBarItemSize).resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero);
    tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(UIColor(hexString: "#c1463e")!, size: tabBarItemSize).resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero);
    // item selected color
    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    // remove default border
    tabBar.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width + 4;
    tabBar.frame.origin.x = -2;

}
}

extension UIImage {

class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0);
    color.setFill();
    UIRectFill(rect);
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}

}
```

**NavigationViewController Class**

```
import UIKit

class MeetsNavigationViewController: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}



}
```

Comment: Can you add some sample code? So we can help you better.

Comment: Sure, just added, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**

It appears that adding items to the navigation bar from the tab bar childs is not possible, but adding items to the tab bar controller is possible, so this is what I did. And I just changed to the title according to my selected tab, I added this method to the tab bar controller:

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
    if item.tag==0{
        navigationItem.title="המפגשים שלי";
    }else{
       navigationItem.title="כל המפגשים";
    }
}
```